# How do you organize NLA editor strips

Tags: nla-editor

The outliner tab/bar is pretty organized, but when you look at the NLA editor it doesn't reflect what you see in the outliner[image]

Comment: How do you fix this? and re-order the tracks?

Comment: As in the speaker name order?  01blah, 02 blah, ... don't think you can.